# REGEXP_SUBSTR Oracle | Extract a string between two delimiters

Tags: sql, oracle, select, substring, regexp-substr

Im trying to extract a name from a column that return a big clob like this one:

```
{ 
   "idStatus":6,
   "atrasoSLA":0.0,
   "atrasoSLAStr":"00:00",
   "baseReports":false,
   "idItemTrabalho":10019,
   "portfolio":"Segurança",
   "servicoRelacionado":"ATIVOS (SEGURANÇA)",
   "idStatusControleSla":8,
   "dataFinalUltimoControleSla":"Sep 3, 2018 11:55:12 AM",
   "grupoExecutor":"Segurança",
   "idGrupoExecutor":71,
   "contrato":"Central de Serviços - SEFAZ-MA",
   "dataHoraCaptura":"Sep 3, 2018 11:42:32 AM",
   "dataHoraFim":"Sep 3, 2018 11:55:12 AM",
   "dataHoraInicio":"Sep 3, 2018 11:42:19 AM",
   "dataHoraInicioSLA":"Sep 3, 2018 11:42:19 AM",
   "dataHoraInicioSLAStr":"09/03/2018 11:42 AM",
   "dataHoraLimite":"Sep 4, 2018 7:42:00 AM",
   "dataHoraLimiteStr":"09/04/2018 07:42 AM",
   "dataHoraSolicitacao":"Sep 3, 2018 11:42:19 AM",
   "dataHoraSolicitacaoStr":"09/03/2018 11:42 AM",
   "demanda":"Requisição",
   "descricao":"\u003cp\u003eRafael reportou que o CITSMART homologa\u0026ccedil;\u0026atilde;o\u0026nbsp;esta\u0026nbsp;offline.\u0026nbsp;\u003c/p\u003e\n",
   "descricaoSemFormatacao":"Rafael reportou que o CITSMART homologação esta offline. ",
   "descrSituacao":"citcorpore.comum.fechada",
   "detalhamentoCausa":"\u003cp\u003eO incidente foi causado devido o servidor de aplica\u0026ccedil;\u0026otilde;es do CITSMART estar em DHCP, com isso o IP 10.1.1.247 foi alterado para outro IP causando a falha na comunica\u0026ccedil;\u0026atilde;o com o APACHE.\u003c/p\u003e\n",
   "emailcontato":"rafael.feitosa@sefaz.ma.gov.br",
   "emailResponsavel":"nilson@sefaz.ma.gov.br",
   "enviaEmailAcoes":"S",
   "enviaEmailCriacao":"S",
   "enviaEmailFinalizacao":"S",
   "faseAtual":"Execução",
   "grupoNivel1":"SDNIVEL1",
   "idAcordoNivelServico":8,
   "idCalendario":2,
   "idContatoSolicitacaoServico":1844,
   "idContrato":2,
   "idFaseAtual":2,
   "idOrigem":1,
   "idPrioridade":5,
   "idServico":70,
   "idServicoContrato":61,
   "idSolicitacaoServico":1559,
   "idSolicitante":2220,
   "idTipoDemandaServico":1,
   "idUnidade":104,
   "idTarefaEncerramento":10019,
   "impacto":"B",
   "nomecontato":"Rafael Brito Feitosa",
   "nomeServico":"ATIVOS (SEGURANÇA) - Análise LOGs/Desempenho/Capacidade/Disponibilidade",
   "nomeTarefa":"Atender solicitacao",
   "nomeUnidadeResponsavel":"COTEC",
   "observacao":" ",
   "origem":"Central de Serviços",
   "prazoCapturaHH":0,
   "prazoCapturaMM":0,
   "prazoHH":8,
   "prazoMM":0,
   "prioridade":"5",
   "responsavel":"Nilson Roniery da Silva Vieira (COTEC)",
   "resposta":"\u003cp\u003ePara solucionar este foi inserido um IP fixo da DMZ EXTERNA e mais o seguintes passos:\u003c/p\u003e\n\n\u003col\u003e\n\t\u003cli\u003eAdicionado IP fixo na m\u0026aacute;quina, sendo ele: 172.20.1.55;\u003c/li\u003e\n\t\u003cli\u003eForam criadas regras no Firewall:\n\t\u003cul\u003e\n\t\t\u003cli\u003e172.20.1.55 --\u0026gt; 10.1.1.56 (BD) porta 1521\u003c/li\u003e\n\t\t\u003cli\u003e172.20.1.55 -\u0026gt;\u0026gt;\u0026nbsp; INTERNET portas 80 e 443\u003c/li\u003e\n\t\t\u003cli\u003eVPN CIT --\u0026gt;\u0026nbsp;172.20.1.55\u003c/li\u003e\n\t\u003c/ul\u003e\n\t\u003c/li\u003e\n\t\u003cli\u003eForam alterados os proxies no apache conforme imagem abaixo\u003cimg src\u003d\"/citsmart/galeriaImagens/1/2/439.png\" style\u003d\"height:105px; width:884px\" /\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\n\t\u003cli\u003eFoi restartado o servi\u0026ccedil;o do citsmart no AS.\u0026nbsp;\n\t\u003cul\u003e\n\t\t\u003cli\u003e\u003cem\u003e#\u0026nbsp;/etc/init.d/citsmart_itsm stop\u003c/em\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\n\t\t\u003cli\u003e\u003cem\u003e# /etc/init.d/citsmart_itsm start\u003c/em\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\n\t\u003c/ul\u003e\n\t\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003c/ol\u003e\n",
   "seqReabertura":0,
   "servico":"ATIVOS (SEGURANÇA) - Análise LOGs/Desempenho/Capacidade/Disponibilidade",
   "situacaoSLA":"A",
   "slaACombinar":"N",
   "solicitante":"Rafael Brito Feitosa",
   "solicitanteUnidade":"Rafael Brito Feitosa",
   "solucaoTemporaria":"N",
   "telefonecontato":"Não disponível.",
   "tempoAtendimentoHH":0,
   "tempoAtendimentoMM":12,
   "tempoAtrasoHH":0,
   "tempoAtrasoMM":0,
   "tempoCapturaHH":0,
   "tempoCapturaMM":0,
   "tempoCapturaSS":13,
   "tempoDecorridoHH":0,
   "tempoDecorridoMM":0,
   "urgencia":"B",
   "ordernacao":0,
   "usuarioDto":{ 
      "idUsuario":635,
      "idEmpregado":635,
      "idPerfilAcessoUsuario":6,
      "idEmpresa":1,
      "login":"sefaz.ma.gov.br\\034013",
      "nomeUsuario":"Nilson Roniery da Silva Vieira",
      "senha":"f04534e4998415904454ae1ceb2040fa05bf548e",
      "status":"A",
      "ldap":"S",
      "email":"nilson@sefaz.ma.gov.br",
      "ldapGroupId":1,
      "fromToken":false
   },
   "idResponsavel":635,
   "idGrupoAtual":71,
   "idGrupoNivel1":2,
   "idTarefa":10019,
   "grupoAtual":"Segurança"
}
```

In this case the name i want is `"Nilson Roniery da Silva"`
And the only thing i know is that the names always come after the `"nomeUsuario":"` and at the end have a "

so, how can i make a select that only brings me the name between "nomeUsuario":" and "

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `json_value` to parse this clob:

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE(mycolumn, '$.usuarioDto.nomeUsuario') FROM mytable
```